# ¿Cómo cargar imágenes con jQuery y Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hola buenas tardes tengo este código pero se como hacer que se actualize el *div* con su ID ejemplo
este div es para ver los datos del archivo .php

```
 <div id="album_paint_content"></div>
```

y estas imágenes en ID tienen el post que quiero ver

> album_content**ID**

```
<img id="album_content1" class="img_thumbnails" src="imagen"/>
<img id="album_content2" class="img_thumbnails" src="imagen"/>
<img id="album_content3" class="img_thumbnails" src="imagen"/>
<img id="album_content4" class="img_thumbnails" src="imagen"/>
```

aquí esta el js para hacer eso pero no se como hacer eso de un ID porque solo se actualiza el primero pero los otros no

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
            $('#album_content').click(function(){
                $("#album_paint_content").load("paint_new.php");
            });
        });
```

bueno espero que me ayudan y gracias

Comment: Debería ser: `$( "#album_paint_content" ).load( "paint_new.php .img_thumbnails" );`. Así te carga sólo los elementos cuya clase sea `img_thumbnails`. No lo he probado, pero debería funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo así:

```
$( "#album_paint_content" ).load( "paint_new.php .img_thumbnails") ...
```

de ese modo obtienes sólo aquellos elementos cuya clase sea `img_thumbnails`.

Si quieres todo el contenido de la página quitas eso y listo.

Aquí un ejemplo, implementando manejo de errores.

Obtendremos los elementos cuya clase sea `title` en esta página de MDN.

```js
$(function()  //document.ready es  obsoleto a partir de jQuery 3
{
  $('#album_content').click(function() 
  {
      var url_elem="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML .title";
     
      $("#album_paint_content").load(url_elem, function(response, status, xhr) 
      {
          if (status == "error") {
            var msg = "Hubo un error: ";
            console.log(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
       }
      });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="album_content">Cargar contenido...</button>
<hr />
<div id="album_paint_content"></div>
```

Comment: quiero que cada imagen tenga su ID como le hago?

Comment: No entiendo @Shareiv. `load` te carga todos los elementos de esa clase, y supongo que otorgará a cada imagen su id. O si el archivo php tiene solamente eso, le quitas el parámetro de la clase para que te traiga todo el archivo. O encierras todo el bloque de imágenes en un `<div class="imagenes">aquí las imágenes</div>` y usas la clase `imagenes` en la petición `load`.

Comment: album_content1 album_content2 album_content3 y que cara uno tenga su ID y se actuzlize en el album_paint_content

Comment: Pero eso es lo que hace el código de la respuesta @Shareiv. Obtiene las imágenes cada una con su id y las pone en `<div id="album_paint_content"></div>`

Comment: no ese id="" no ejemplo gato1 gato2 el numero el dato

Comment: Sugiero que edites tu pregunta y expliques qué es lo que quieres, porque no estoy entendiendo nada @Shareiv

Comment: mira tengo 4 imagenes album_content1 album_content2 pero solo se actualiza la album_content1 en el div album_paint_content como hago para que tambien album_content2 se actualize ?

Comment: OMG, como está planteada la pregunta lo que se entiende es que tú tienes un archivo desde el cual pulsas al botón que hace la petición `load` al archivo `paint_new.php` y que en ese archivo está esto: `<img id="album_content1" class="img_thumbnails" src="imagen"/>
<img id="album_content2" class="img_thumbnails" src="imagen"/>
<img id="album_content3" class="img_thumbnails" src="imagen"/>...`. Pero al parecer, todo eso está en el mismo archivo  y tú quieres llamar otro contenido que está en `paint_new.php`. **Debes presentar ese contenido, el que hay en `paint_new.php` en la pregunta**.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67618/discussion-between-shareiv-and-a-cedano).

Comment: mira quiero hacer algo como esto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104744/onclick-on-div-load-content-from-database-on-other-div

Comment: pero no me funciona